# Running a Visual Studio Online project on Macbook Pro

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, localhost

I need help trying to run a Visual Studio project on a Mac. Recently purchased a new Mac and need to make sure the machine is setup correctly for .net development.

So far I've cloned the project from Visual Studio Online and now need to be able to run this through localhost and also edit the files.

All I can see in the project is the .sln, which I have no real expertise on except for what I read online about it been a solutions files.

Any help out there?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use Visual Studio in MAC

Bootcamp –

Boot Camp is a multi boot utility included with Apple Inc.'s OS X that assists users in installing Microsoft Windows operating systems on Intel-based Macintosh computers

This is the Apple way of allowing you to run Windows on an Intel-based Mac. Simply use the built-in Bootcamp Assistant, make a partition and install Windows. Once done, you can easily boot into Windows instead of OSX and reuse all of the I/O (input-output) drivers for peripherals. In this mode, Windows is running natively “on the metal” and you get the full performance benefits. This of course means you can install Visual Studio and write C# all day, just as in a Windows machine.

Virtual Machines –

If choosing which OS to boot into isn’t your cup of tea, your other option is to run Windows in a virtual machine (VM) with OSX acting as the host OS. There is dedicated software that will do the heavy lifting for your VM – like managing virtualization, memory and peripherals. Parallels and VMWare Fusion are two excellent options for running Windows VMs on your Mac. With customizable virtualization, resource fine-tuning options and easy switch-ability between Windows/OSX , you should be rocking Windows running as a VM in no time. And just as easily, you can install Visual Studio inside your Windows 
VM and write C# to your heart’s content.

more on [installation](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/write-c-mac-like-champ/)

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't really want to run Windows on my Mac, was hoping there was an alternative. I've ended up just using my Windows machine and installed Visual Studio.

Comment: As a Front-end dev, I need to be able to update the styling. How do I get to the stylesheets in the solution?

Comment: Cancel that last comment. I was in the wrong branch to complete my development.